# SVN Performance Issues with IPV6

Tags: performance, svn, ipv6

I'm using SlikSVN's 64-bit subversion server for source control.  I noticed that a few applications were taking a really long time to perform simple actions with repositories the other day, such as browsing the repository, committing etc, and I thought it was a fault within the applications themselves.

I tried the same actions logged into my network via VPN however, and they were all super-speedy.  The only difference was that I was connecting to the subversion server via the IP address (v4) rather than hostname.  After a few tests, I found that the problem seemed to have something to do with IPV6.

Disabling IPV6 made most of the performance issues disappear, but I'm not sure I want this to be the solution...

IPV6 seems to be supported by SlikSVN - it even has a -6 parameter (which I have tried) to make svnserve prefer ipv6 connections, but it doesn't seem to help the issue all that much.  I'm also using the latest versions of the applications which are having issues (AnkhSVN is one of them), and believe them to also support IPv6.

I'd be tempted to add an entry to the hosts file so that name resolution for the SVN host always resolves to an IPv4 address, but this still feels a bit hacky to me.

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of issue?

Many thanks,
Nick

Comment: Do you actually have a working IPv6 connection?  When it takes a long time, is it actually connecting via IPv6, or is it trying IPv6 and then falling back to IPv4 when the 6 doesn't work.

Comment: Problems like this is the reason all current browsers implement the happy eyeballs approach. The same problem applies to many other applications, and the real solution would be for those applications to apply the same fix.

Comment: The real solution isn't to implement happy eyeballs in thousands of applications, but to provide it in a couple of libraries that get you connected.